# Query using Eloquent Laravel using "as"

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, eloquent

How do you know the other code to get this query in laravel using eloquent?

```
$variable_value= DB::select(
 'SELECT
  sv.VARIABLE_NAME as sv_variable_name, sv.TYPE as sv_type, sv.ADDRESS as sv_address, sv.VALUE as sv_value,
  ms.VARIABLE_NAME as ms_variable_name, ms.TYPE as ms_type, ms.ADDRESS as ms_address, ms.VALUE as ms_value
  FROM MASTER_VARIABLES ms
  JOIN SLAVE_VARIABLES sv ON ms.SLV_ADDRESS=sv.ID_VARIABLE'
);
```

Thank you for your help, guys!

Comment: Have you tried writing any Eloquent code yet?

Comment: not yet. because I dont have any reference to write it. @TimBiegeleisen

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's all in the [documentation](https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/queries). Give it a read?

> ## [# Selects](https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/queries#selects)
>
> ### Specifying A Select Clause
>
> You may not always want to select all columns from a database table. Using the select method, you can specify a custom select clause for the query:
>
> `$users = DB::table('users')->select('name', 'email as user_email')->get();`
>
> ## [# Joins](https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/queries#joins)
>
> ### Inner Join Clause
>
> The query builder may also be used to write join statements. To perform a basic "inner join", you may use the join method on a query builder instance. The first argument passed to the join method is the name of the table you need to join to, while the remaining arguments specify the column constraints for the join. You can even join to multiple tables in a single query:
>
> `$users = DB::table('users')
>             ->join('contacts', 'users.id', '=', 'contacts.user_id')
>             ->join('orders', 'users.id', '=', 'orders.user_id')
>             ->select('users.*', 'contacts.phone', 'orders.price')
>             ->get();`

```php
$query = DB::table('MASTER_VARIABLES as ms')
->select(
    'sv.VARIABLE_NAME as sv_variable_name',
    'sv.TYPE as sv_type',
    'sv.ADDRESS as sv_address',
    'sv.VALUE as sv_value',
    'ms.VARIABLE_NAME as ms_variable_name',
    'ms.TYPE as ms_type',
    'ms.ADDRESS as ms_address',
    'ms.VALUE as ms_value'
)
->join('SLAVE_VARIABLES as sv', 'ms.SLV_ADDRESS', '=', 'sv.ID_VARIABLE')
->get();
```